# Correct way to notify http client of error after partial response has been sent in Java http

Tags: java, http, browser

What is the correct behavior for an HTTP server if an error occurs while writing a streaming response to the client?  Say for example, the server wrote part of the body to response outputstream and the response is committed with a 200 status code. While generating another chunk of the response body, we encounter an error on the server.  Is there a mechanism to return an indicator to the browser that the content is not complete because of an error on the server?

In my particular usecase I am requesting a dynamically generated JavaScript file using a `script` tag.

Comment: The only thing you can do is close the connection. The server announced some content with the length X (via the Content-Length response header) and the client can choose how long to wait for that. You cannot use the http rotocol to send control codes parallel to that. A way to avoid this is to fully generate your content and only then send it out, this way you can set an appropriate http response code if something fails.

Comment: I was thinking about buffering the content in memory, which is what I do today, but we want to reduce server memory used during a request.

Comment: Is there a way to send an indicator, like a [Trailer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Trailer) header to indicate to the browser something is wrong?

Comment: If you can't write the response you can't write an error either. Just close the connection. Nothing else you can possibly do. And buffering the response won't tell you whether you can write it. *Maybe* you could do something with chunked streaming mode, if you can control the chunking yourself.

Comment: I can white to the body of the response, but I can't change anything in the headers.